# Triangulation method to create multipatch objects (decomposition of polygon surfaces)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, 3d-analyst, arcscene, multipatch

Which triangulation method or algorithm does arcscene use to create multipatch parts (patches) as you see in the attaching picture. The algorith decompose the polygon area into a set of triangles using vertices of the polygon object. But which method is it? It is not delanuay or ear clipping in my opinion but which one I can not figure it out any help??

[image: triangulation of polygons]

Answer (score 1):

This Esri whitepaper might get you started on the path to your answer:
http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/multipatch-geometry-type.pdf

Or if you want Delaunay triangulation, you can try out this tool:
http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=6e9bc6cbf93d4939b2eb04ff8519be47

Comment: I have already read the white paper but there is no information about triangulation method in it.

Comment: Did you try asking over at GeoNet? Sounds like the information you seek might only be known internally, and their people watch those forums.

Comment: yes I asked but unfortunately could'nt get an answer